# How to share text to news feed of the facebook in flutter

Tags: facebook, flutter

I use social_share package but only share to story of the facebook.
How to share text to news feed of the facebook?
Thanks!

[Share newsfeed facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpOIz.png)

Comment: this package only supports Share on Story not on Facebook timeline.

Comment: What have you tried, what is your approach and where dit you run stuck?

Comment: i can not find a package can share text to newsfeed of the facebook.

Answer (score 1):

I used [esys_flutter_share](https://pub.dev/packages/esys_flutter_share) to share the text and photos to news feed and story of the Facebook. Check below how it's working.

Share Text

```
Share.text('my text title', 'This is my text to share with other applications.', 'text/plain');
```

Share Photo

```
final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/image1.png');
await Share.file('esys image', 'esys.png', bytes.buffer.asUint8List(), 'image/png', text: 'My optional text.');
```

Might it will be help you.

Comment: I want to click a button, app will navigate newsfeed facebook like this image 
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpOIz.png)